# Laravel 5 Routing admin site error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I can't go to the admin part of my site. I'm landing always on the main site. This problem is only with admin, every another routes working perfectly.

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     // Login, logout
     Route::get('admin', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@index'));
     Route::post('admin/login', array('as' => 'cms_login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login', 'before' => 'csrf'));
     Route::get('admin/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AuthController@logout'));
}
```

AuthController:

```
public function index(){
    // Show login form
    return view('backend/pages/login');
}
```

Doesn't matter what I do, I landing always on the home screen www.example.com if I try to call www.example.com/admin.

Comment: Can you show the output of running `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I just added a pic about the routes

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: Which routes specifically is it you're unable to visit? And which route does it behave like you're visiting instead? And yes - if you're using the latest version of Laravel 5.2 having the web middleware group is redundant, and can in some cases cause problems.

Comment: laravel 5.2 I tried it with and without the middleware group. I can't reach the www.example.com/admin (login form - Authcontroller index() function) and if I call directly the loginform without the authcotroller index() function: 
Route::get('admin', function() {
        return view('backend/pages/login');
    });
I can see the login form, but if I click on login (Authcontroller login() function) I'll land on the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the app/http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Here was "return redirect('/');" that's why I landed always on the home screen